# Codeigniter url not found when HTTPS

Tags: php, codeigniter, https

i have problem using https connection like (https://www.bla.com/logout) in codeigniter,its working when im using http like (http://www.bla.com/logout) only.
Any ideas regarding this? Please help me

SECURED

[https]www.bla.com/index.php/logout -working

[https]www.bla.com/logout - not working

NON SECURED

[http]www.bla.com/logout - working

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate installed? Is port 443 configured on your web server? Nginx/Apache needs to be configured to handle this. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps

Comment: @RedGlobe yes ssl certificate installed,i can access like (https://www.bla.com) with green lock,but when url like (https://www.bla.com/test/test) url not found, but its working if not HTTPS

Comment: I got the same problem than you. Could you get any sollution? Thks

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem with you. In my case, the problem is that I set "AllowOverride All" for non ssl directory and "AllowOverride None" for ssl directory in my httpd.conf.

Please make sure that "AllowOverride" option is set to "AllowOverride All" in your httpd.conf for both SSL and non SSL directory.

```
<Directory "/var/www/nonssl_dir/">
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/ssl_dir/">
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure that you already installed SSL on your server. If you don't have SSL certificate, you can buy a SSL certificate from 3rd party service like Go Daddy or else. Then install it to your server.

After that you can test the SSL ready by calling the https protocol, like: https://www.bla.com/

If it works, then you just need to add some code on your Code Igniter config file to handle the SSL, something like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 'https' : 'http') . "://example.com/";
```

Comment: not working. Yes ssl is installed on server, the problem on ly is when i access like: (https://www.bla.com/logout) got url not found

Comment: when you open the https://bla.com/, is it pointed to your correct home directory? since the configuration of home directory for port 80 and 443 is different

Comment: if using index.php is working, consider to check the rewrite configuration on htaccess or check if the SSL server have the rewrite_module on